# degenerate in simplex method

Tags: algorithm, linear-programming

I am reading about linear programming using simplex method in book Introduction to Algorithm Design and analysis.

I am having difficulty in understanding text. Here is text snippet.

> The principal advantage of the standard form lies in the simple
>   mechanism it provides for identifying extreme points of the feasible
>   region. For the general case of a problem with m equations in  n
>   unknowns (n ≥ m), n − m variables need to be set to zero to get a
>   system of m equations in m unknowns. If the system obtained has a
>   unique solution—as any nondegenerate system of linear equations with
>   the number of equations equal to the number of unknowns does—we have a
>   basic solution; its coordinates set to zero before solving the system
>   are called nonbasic, and its coordinates obtained by solving the
>   system are called basic.

My questions on above text are

1. What is nondegenerate system of linear equations?
2. What does author mean by unique solution here in above context?

Answer (score -1):

As author says, "For the general case of a problem with m equations in n unknowns (n ≥ m), (n − m) variables need to be set to zero to get a system of m equations in m unknowns." So when you set (n-m) variables as zero, you will have a system of m equations with m variables.

Let me explain with an example and basic math. Suppose that m = 2,  and the system of equations you have is :

```
x + y = 2 & x - y = 0
```

So this system of equations has "unique solution", where `(x = 1 & y = 1)`

Now suppose that m = 3, and the system of equations you have is :

```
x + y + z = 3, x + y - z = 1, & x + y = 2
```

In this case, any point with z = 1 and satisfying equation x + y = 2 will satisfy all the equations. For example, (x = 1, y = 1, & z = 1), (x = 2, y = 0, & z = 1), and (x = 4, y = - 2, & z = 1). So here you have more than one solution to this system of equations, so you will say that this system of equations has "multiple solutions".

Now let us talk about degeneracy. Assuming that you get unique solution to the system of equations, If you solve system of m equations with m variables, you will get numerical value for all m variables. If any of these m variables have their numerical value equal to zero, you will say that solution is degenerate. By non-degenerate, author means that all of the variables have non-zero value in solution. Degeneracy tends to increase the number of simplex iterations before reaching the optimal solution.

Now let us talk a little about simplex method. Suppose you have set (n-m) out of n variables as zero (as author says), and you get an unique non-degenerate solution. You say this solution as basic solution. But their is catch here, you don't know which of (n-m) variables out of n variables have to be set as zero to find optimal solution. In theory, you will have n_combinatorial_(n-m) basic solutions to evaluate. This is where simplex method helps. It helps you in identifying optimal set of variables to be set as zero in order to find optimal solution. Once you have optimally identified variables to be set as zero, and your reduced system of equations have unique solution, then solution to this system of equations is the optimal solution.

I hope it helps :-)